# Sumar con grupby

Tags: laravel

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar grupby

En mi ejercicio debo contar la cantidad de entradas que se vendieron y sumar el total de la recaudación en dinero.

```
$entradas = Ingresostaquilla::groupBy('tipo')
->selectRaw('count(*) as cantidad, tipo')
->get();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora logre hacer el conteo por tipo de entrada, pero no sé cómo hacer que sume el total de dinero que recaudo cada entrada, ayuda por favor

Model:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Debo emplear SUM, pero como lo hago con grupby?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos. Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", generalmente no es bien recibida en la comunidad. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto lo que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste.

Comment: Quizas este post puede ayudarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887708/laravel-eloquent-sum-with-groupby